# YII2: Sort and Filter according to date OR time from a timestamp field in DB

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm using YII 2.

I have a DB with a "timestamp" field, in the view I have a GridView where I devided the DB field "timestamp" into two different columns.

formatted as date and the other one formatted as time.

I would like to know if it's possible to sort & filter the two different columns in my GridView using only one "timestamp" field in my DB ?

Comment: Show us your gridview columns config

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution using mysql you can split the timestamp Field using

```
dateformat(yourtimestamp, %d/%m/%Y) as Date
dateformat(yourtimestamp, %H:%i) as Time
Order by Date, Time
```

Comment: But you must know that this will not be indexed and query might execute much much longer. It can be better to split this column in to date and time for better performance.

Comment: my thinking is that when using only "timestamp", it's cleaner than using two fields (date and time) . knowing that my date and time are not dynamic but set to creation date/time. not sure if my thinking is correct though.

Comment: @Glapa , I think you're right, even if it's possible to do this in "YII2 Framework"  or in "SELECT",  it's probably not the best thing to do. I think I'll just split my "timestamp" into separate "date" and "time".